# Kettle operation window get stuck at Linux OS，and always not responding

Tags: kettle

I use VNC to open the Kettle that on Linux server,but it is always not responding, it maybe works after a while,then not responding agagin when I click one channel！Only kettle has this problem，other applications work well！

Comment: Kettle use swt which uses gtk. Which version of kettle do you use? (Latest version of swt library uses gtk3)

Comment: the kettle version is 5.2, I restart the Linux machine today,then kettle run more smoothly，maybe you can tell me some possible reasons about this problem,thanks! @simar

Comment: Eclipse/SWT 4.3.x: GTK+ 2.10.0 only and its dependencies. Ensure that u have gtk libraries installed on your machine same version gtk2.10+. It might help.